# Run command that has variable in remote server via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, script, remote

I want to run a command for change the ownership of /home directories. Example

---

Example:

```
[root@remoteServer]# ls -l /home
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root  root  4096  Sep  9  2014  user1
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root  root  4096  Sep  9  2014  user2
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root  root  4096  Sep  9  2014  user3
[root@remoteServer]#
[root@remoteServer]#id user1
uid=1101(user1) gid=1200(groupO)
[root@remoteServer]#id user2
uid=1102(user2) gid=1200(groupO)
[root@remoteServer]#id user2
uid=1103(user3) gid=1200(groupO)
```

I will change the ownership of this directories like this:

```
[root@remoteServer]# ls -l /home
drwxr-xr-x. 17 user1  groupO  4096  Sep  9  2014  user1
drwxr-xr-x. 17 user2  groupO  4096  Sep  9  2014  user2
drwxr-xr-x. 17 user3  groupO  4096  Sep  9  2014  user3
```

---

I use a script for this from localServer. The script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(cat ipListFile)
do
        ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no $ip "for i in /home/*; do chown $(echo $i | awk -F"home/" '{ print $2 }'):groupO $i; done;"
done
```

There is a problem at **for** loop. This loop is working at remoteServer local. But I cannot use this command at localServer as remote script for remoteServer.
When I try this command at localServer the "$i" variable has ridiculous value like "17123891".

Comment: Try using `$$i` instead of `$i`. It will escape the `$$` on the *local* server and the *remote* server's shell will receive `$i`. I can't test this right now (hence comment), but it should work. Make sure you test it though.

Comment: @NathanShiraini I would have user `\$` to escape `$`, `$$` is for makefile.

Comment: oh. I saw your solution now @Archemar Thanks. I typed this solution as an answer to this question. It works. If you wish you can add the answer and then I can accept it.

Comment: @Archemar Indeed, I forgot. I only used this trick in a Makefile, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mistake with change the Nathan'a answer. The solution is using a "\" character with each "$" chararcters like "\$". So the final command is:

```
    #!/bin/bash
for ip in $(cat ipListFile)
do
        ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no $ip "for i in /home/*; do chown \$(echo \$i | awk -F"home/" '{ print \$2 }'):groupO \$i; done;"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

simplest solution would be to send the script, then execute it.

```
for ...
do
   scp script.sh $ip:/tmp
   ssh $ip bash /tmp/sript.sh
   ssh $ip rm /tmp/sript.sh
done
```

to avoid multiple timeout

```
for ...
do
   if scp script.sh $ip:/tmp
   then
      ssh $ip bash /tmp/sript.sh
      sh $ip rm /tmp/sript.sh
   fi
done
```

if every `/home/userX` should belong to `userX`

you can try

```
"ls -d /home/* | xargs -L1 basename | while read h ; do chown \$h:group0 /home/\$h ; done"
```

Comment: Thanks, it's an useful solution. I found my mistake. I'll give you a upvote when I got 15 rep.